# Cannot capture warning output generated by Write-Warning (into a WarningVariable)

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-2.0

Consider this line:

```
Write-Warning "test" -wv +t
```

If I run this and verify the contents of `$t` afterwards, I get this:

```
Message   InvocationInfo                             PipelineIterationInfo
-------   --------------                             ---------------------
test      System.Management.Automation.Invocation... {0, 0, 0}
```

This is what I would indeed expect.

Now, if I turn this line of code into a script, like so:

```
function WarnTest {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    Write-Warning "test" 
}
```

and then make a simple function call like this:

```
WarnTest -wv +q
$q
```

`$q` remains empty.  I'm a bit baffled by this - I was under the impression that `[CmdletBinding()]` made sure that any write-warning in the function would be sent to the warning stream, and could therefore be caught with the `-WarningVariable` parameter.

Can anyone shed a light on this?

The purpose for which I need this is a function to test which servers are online (and send these to the standard output) where I can also capture the warnings of those which are offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead on v2:

```
function WarnTest {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    $pscmdlet.WriteWarning("test")
}
```

Your original function seems to work correctly on PowerShell v3.

Comment: Once again you save the day.  I have no idea why it doesn't work on V2, but I'm glad I have a workaround.  Thank you!